instrumented tests running on unitTest task [Compose multiplatform]
We have recently added some compose MP ui test following the official documentation.
Test themselves work perfectly and I can run on my three targets with no problems.
The problems shows up on CI now as when we run ./gradlew testDebugUnitest it's now picking up the instrumented test as well on obviously failing.
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.toLowerCase(java.util.Locale)" because "android.os.Build.FINGERPRINT" is null

My assumption is that it's due to the  test being added in commonTest and adding
@OptIn(ExperimentalKotlinGradlePluginApi::class)
                instrumentedTestVariant.sourceSetTree.set(KotlinSourceSetTree.test)

Somehow makes android uses all sourcets and thus test. But then again thats how the official doc say we should add this new ui tests.
Is there something extra I'm missing? Should I be running uniTest with a different task ?
Edit:
I guess the issue is that the test is in commonTest and thats why its picked up. But again what would be the way to go here
